# minikube resolve company internal IPs

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes, virtualbox, minikube

We are just getting started with Docker and Kubernetes. I am using minikube with the virtualbox driver on Mac OS X intel. I have a container that connects to our remote Oracle Database which has an internal ip address. I have no issue connecting when I run the container locally. I also have no issue if I run a cluster using the Docker Kubernetes. But when I use minikube then I am unable to properly resolve the address. When I run nslookup within the cluster I see the ip address but as a non-authoritative answer. Is it minikube or virtualbox that needs a setting changed on it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I switched to Hyperkit and I'm not having any issues. So it was definitely something with the Virtualbox config.